# Need to update id as per change in time column

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with the below schema and records.

```
id    use_time
x1    10.01
x1    10.02
x1    10.04
x1    11.09 
x1    11.23
x1    12.08
x2    01.01
x2    01.04
x2    01.23
x2    03.44
x2    04.31
```

And I need to update the id whenever there is a difference between use_time of more than 30 min.
That is for every 30 min the id should be unique.

The new rows should be like this

```
id  use_time
x1  10.01
x1  10.02
x1  10.04
x11 11.09
x11 11.23
x12 12.08
x2  1.01
x2  1.04
x2  1.23
x21 3.44
x23 4.31
```

In the above table, on the 4th record the time difference is of an hour so the id is updated to x11(new) and the next time difference is less than 30 min so the id stays to x11 and again on 6th record the difference is more than 30 min so the id becomes x12. and same for other ids too.

Can any body please suggest.

Comment: Oracle or Snowflake? Those are two very different database products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `lag` and `sum` analytical function as following:

```
SELECT ID || CASE WHEN S > 0 THEN S END AS NEW_ID, 
       USE_TIME FROM
      (select ID, 
              use_time,
              sum(diff) over (partition by id order by use_time) S
         from
         (select id, use_time,
                 case when (use_time - lag(use_time) 
                      over (partition by id order by use_time)) * 24 * 60 > 30 
                 then 1 else 0 end as diff
           from your_table))
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af920173512a92d786348ee64f417e5d)

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help, but there is a small issue still.It can update the new_id to id+1, but again the next id is id+0 as diff is zero. i need the next id to be id+1 as well. like in the above example the 5th record is to be x11 but is still showing x10, since the difference of time is less than 30 min 4th and 5th. And again for the next record which have more than 30, should have id+2 but it will do id+1 yet.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then please accept it so that it will be marked as resolved.

Comment: Accept it on Stack overflow. It is still in not accepted status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumulative sums and `lag()`:

```
select id || (case when sum(is_change) over (partition by id order by use_time) > 0
                   then sum(is_change) over (partition by id order by use_time)
              end),
       use_time
from (select t.*,
             (case when lag(use_time over (partition by id order by use_time) < use_time
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as is_change
      from t
     ) t
```